# Ubuntu 13.10 internet connection problem

Tags: 13.10, connection

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my HP Pavilion dv7.  Most of the time, when I close my laptop, and then reopen it, I cannot connect to the internet, especially if I was only connected to wifi when I closed it.  Networks are not displayed.  I used the rfkill list all command, and it showed that neither my lan or wifi was hard or soft blocked.  To get the connection back, I have to restart my computer, which is obviously annoying, so I'd like to get it to reconnect automatically.  I've been keeping up with updates. What might I do to fix this?

Comment: Please be more specific about "I cannot connect to the internet". Is your wireless card not recognized anymore? Or do you have to reconnect to the network manually? Do you receive any specific error messages? Is WiFi disabled after resuming from suspend (verify with `rfkill list all` from the command line)? And what do you do to restore the ability to connect to the network again? Please [edit] your question to include those details. Keen in mind that we can't see your screen, so we rely on the information you include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is that when you close your laptop. It goes to hibernate state. Whenever, you reopen it. The wifi device remains idle or it doesn't refresh DNS and doesn't try to reconnect with the wifi router.

You need to either reconnect with wifi router or you should try to clear DNS of our computer.

The other solution of this problem is to specify static ip-address to make wifi connection with the router.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How would I reconnect to the wifi router? No wifi networks, or even wired networks, are shown when this problem occurs.  I'm not very fluent with computers, so any more explanation on how I would accomplish these remedies would be appreciated.